# Reduce space inside the boxplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to remove the extra space inside the plot's border

```
plt.boxplot(parkingData_agg['occupancy'], 0, 'rs', 0, 0.75)
plt.tight_layout() # This didn't work. Maybe it's not for the purpose I am thinking it is used for.
plt.yticks([0],['Average Occupancy per slot'])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 1), dpi=5) #Tried to change the figsize but it didn't work
plt.show()
```

[image]

The desired plot is as shown in the 2nd plot from left in the diagram below
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the space in `y`-direction? Try playing with `plt.ylim()`. `tight_layout()` is for managing space between subplots.

Comment: I guess you forgot to tell us how you would like the plot to look like instead.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for your answer. It was helpful. I wanted to reduce the padding between the boxplot and the border of the plot  :)

Comment: Still pretty unclear, there are essentially [those options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNuk2.png). You did not describe which one you want.

Comment: Apologies. I'll try to be clear the next time. I'll add this with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use subplots_adjust

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2))
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axes.boxplot(parkingData_agg['occupancy'], 0, 'rs', 0, 0.75)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.6, bottom=0.4)

#plt.boxplot(parkingData_agg['occupancy'], 0, 'rs', 0, 0.75)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.yticks([0],['Average Occupancy per slot'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

The order of commands in the code is a bit chaotic.

- You need to define a figure, *before* the plotting command (otherwise a second figure is produced).
- You also need to call `tight_layout` *after* setting the ticklabels, such that the long ticklabel can be accounted for.
- To have the tick at position 0 match the position of the boxplot, it would need to be set to that position (`pos=[0]`)

Those changes would lead to the following plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rayleigh(scale=7, size=100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2), dpi=100)

plt.boxplot(data, False, sym='rs', vert=False, whis=0.75, positions=[0])

plt.yticks([0],['Average Occupancy per slot'])

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

You may then change the `widths` of the boxplot(s) to match the desired outcome, e.g.

```
plt.boxplot(..., widths=[0.75])
```

[image]

You may of course put your plot in a subplot, not to have the axes fill the entire space of the figure, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rayleigh(scale=7, size=100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=100)
ax = plt.subplot(3,1,2)

ax.boxplot(data, False, sym='rs', vert=False, whis=0.75, positions=[0], widths=[0.5])

plt.yticks([0],['Average Occupancy per slot'])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]